# Javascript substring not working as expected

Tags: javascript

```
var test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    alert(test.substring(i,1));
}
```

I expected each alert to return each letter of the alphabet individually.

Instead, the first 5 alerts displayed as follows.  Why?

```
a
b
bc
bcd
bcde
```

Comment: You've mixed up `substring()` with `substr()`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is documented in the language's API

Comment: if you want each character only use `.charAt(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    console.log(test.substring(i,i+1));
}
```

actually, it's

```
substring(start, end)
```

not

```
substring(start, length)
```

unlike substr, which is indeed, substr(start, length)

Answer (score 0):

If "start" is greater than "end", this method (**substring**) will swap the two arguments, meaning **str.substring(1,4) == str.substring(4,1)**.
Use:

```
for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    alert(test[i]);
}
```